# Add ELSE in SELECT statement MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, triggers

So what Im trying is to add ELSE or the kind of condition that adds the exeception to the current rule. I have this before insert trigger right now:

```
SET new.perfId = (SELECT cust.webId FROM cust where cust.regTime=new.regTime);
```

I would like to add an ELSE to that statement, something like:

```
SET new.perfId = (SELECT cust.webId FROM cust where cust.regTime=new.regTime) ELSE blabla
```

How should this be set in order query is correct?

Thank you.

Comment: Your question doesn't make sense.  `else` is something you do after an `if`.  Please describe the logic you actually want to implement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you mean, that your condition is that the `select` doesn't return `null`, you can use `coalesce()`.

```
SET new.perfId = COALESCE((SELECT cust.webId FROM cust where cust.regTime=new.regTime), 'blabla');
```

`COALESCE()` returns the first of its parameters which isn't `NULL`.

Answer (score 0):

You could use [COALESCE](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/comparison-operators.html#function_coalesce):

From the docs:

> Returns the first non-NULL value in the list, or NULL if there are no
>   non-NULL values.

```
mysql> SELECT COALESCE(NULL,1);
        -> 1 
mysql> SELECT COALESCE(NULL,NULL,NULL);
        -> NULL
```

You would end up with:

```
SET new.perfId = (SELECT COALESCE(cust.webId,"BLABLA") 
                  FROM cust where cust.regTime=new.regTime);
```

Comment: Thank you Filipe, COALESCE definitely was the thing missing :)